# How can i get count(*) from SQL Using getHibernateTemplate()?

Tags: java, hibernate, count

I want to get the number of DEVICES from a table and show the results on my Html page , i have the following Code and when i run this code i get the Null pointer Exception in my bean :

DashboardDaoImp.java // Dao implementation

```
public int getNumberOfDevices(){

    return DataAccessUtils.intResult(getHibernateTemplate().find("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT deviceid) from Device"));
}
```

DashboardDao.java // Dao Interface

```
public interface DashbordDao {

int getNumberOfDevices();
```

}

DashboardBoImp.java // Bo implementation

```
DashbordDao dashbordDao;

@Override
public int getNumberOfDevices() {

    return dashbordDao.getNumberOfDevices();
}
```

DashboardBoImp.java // Bo interface

```
public interface DashbordBo {

int getNumberOfDevices();   
}
```

DashboardBean.java // My bean

```
public int getNumberOfDevices()
    {
    samssnb_device = dashboardBo.getNumberOfDevices();

    return samssnb_device;
    }
```

// My Html page

```
<h3>#{dashbord.getNumberOfDevices()}<sup style="font-size: 20px"></sup></h3>
              <p>Number of devices </p>
```

// Stack Trace

[Stack Trace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tbGq.png)

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace so we can see where the NPE happens?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe , done !

Comment: So the NPE happens in `DashboardBean`. Most likely `dashboardBo` is still `null`. Check where you initialize/assign the variable.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe , dashboardBo is a DashbordBo type implemented by DashbordBoImp ! i declared him as : `DashbordBo dashbordBo;`

Comment: Yes, but you need to assign something to that variable otherwise, it is `null`. Or are you using a Dependency Injection framework like Spring ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe , yes i use spring as framework !

Comment: I suggest to read more about Spring then first. You need to use `@Autowired` to have Spring inject the component. You also need to define your components in XML or in Java or use classpath scanning to have Spring find them.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe , ok ty wim !